# How can i run a method on resume from other/inner view but not on opening the app?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new in iOS and i am developing at a the moment small recipes application. The main view which opens first when opening the application is table view which contains the recipes. When clicking on "Add" new view opens from which i am able to create new recipe for the table. I am adding additional line to the table before i go to new view from which i am adding the recipe.
The problem i have is that if i click on cancel in the new view and return to the table view a new line is added anyway, empty line. I understand that i need to update the table in "viewWillAppear" by checking if the new recipe was created or not. The problem that i have is that in my scenario no recipe created and if i remove a line from table in "viewWillAppear" then it will be removed every time:

1. I open the application
2. I return from edit of a recipe.

Can you please suggest some solution?

Comment: How is your data model structured? How do you store, add to, and remove from your list of recipes? How does your table view data source utilize the model to interact with the table view?

Comment: I use a mutablearray which contains data by default from which i load the data to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create the new line in the table in the first place. That's not the way to increase the number of rows in the table view. When you create a new recipe, you add that to the array (or other data structure) that you use to populate the table, and when you return to the table view, call reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: if necessary.